# Is using System.Net.Mail.MailAddress to validate email valid?

Tags: .net, validation, email

```
        try
        {
            new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("email here");            
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {

        }
```

when i use email "invalidEmailAddress" the result is valid
but when i use "golf@gmail" without .com it becomes valid

Comment: In an cooperation environment, a domain does not have to have .com/net/org... 'gmail' could be a valid domain, so, the email golf@gmail could be a valid email address internally.

usually, people use regular expression to valid email address. there are lots of examples.